# Looping until multiple conditions reached in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, loops, conditional-statements

So i am trying to create a program that can find a number that can be divided by numbers 1-20.  I know that i will have to use the following simple code concepts:

I know how loops work and how to create a loop that runs until a condition is met.  Is there a simple was to run a loop until several conditions are met?

Comment: I recommend you read about `logical operators` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while ( condition1 && condition2 && condition3... ) {}
```

or

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n && condition1 && condition2... ) {}
```

Obviously these will loop while the conditions are true, not until the conditions are met.  Its a simple change in the logic though to get the result you want

**EDIT**

Ane example of the kind of loop youre looking for could be like:

```
int number = ...;//initialized somewhere, this is what we're checking
BOOL divisible = YES;
for ( int i = 1; i <= 20 && divisible; ++i )
{
    if ( (number % i) != 0 )
        divisible = NO;//not divisible by i
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks.  I thought at first commas would do it but it is the &&.  Thanks.

Comment: there is also `||`, use them wisely depending on how you want your logic to be evaluated

Comment: Ok.  One last thing.  For the for loop, is "i < n" a condition or something else?

Comment: @user1518915 It is a random condition.

Comment: @user1518915 It is a condition, so for example, if you wanted to have a loop that checked if a number is divisible by numbers 1-20 you could have a loop that looks like the one in my edit

Comment: number should be an integral type, for floats, % is not defined

Comment: @H2CO3 you are correct, my mistake.  I changed my train of thought on how to detect divisibility halfway through writing that

Answer (score 0):

Good answers in play, but I think it's good to mention the `break` operator in this discussion. Any loop, at any time, can be terminated using this operator. This can be helpful if you do not know all of the parameters which might go out-of-bounds, and you want to have a way of breaking the loop for reasons you may not have explicitly anticipated (i.e. perhaps your connection to a resource is no longer available...)

```
NSError *error = nil;
while(true) {
  // run your app
  if(error) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a number is divisible by all numbers from 1 to 20 then it is divisible by the LCM of 1 to 20 so divisibility test is if(!(n%232792560)).

Further if m = pq | n then p|n, q|n so to explicitly test you only need to check for divisibility by primes. i.e if the number is not even then there is no need to check for divisibility by 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18 or 20. This reduces the test to the number being congruent to the 8th primorial = 9699690

---

OK, perhaps on second reading not as explicit as I should like: the expanded test looks like (by de Morgan's theorem)

```
if(!(n%19 || n%17 || n%16 || n%13 || n%11 || n%9 || n%7 || n%5))
    // number is divisible by 1..20
```